# Swift - UITableView doesn't complete scrolling when tapping status bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

I have a UITableView with dynamic cells (one prototype) inside a UIViewController. Each cell has the same identifier so they're reused. The height of the cell is elaborated runtime because it contains an image loaded asynchronously and with different ratio. In other words, it works exactly like Instagram home, with pagination too.

The problem is that when I tap the status bar, it starts to scroll to the top but it stops before reaching the top. If i manually scroll to the top, go back to the end of the table and then tap status bar, it works fine. Any idea where the problem may be? I think it depends on reusing cells...

```
extension ResultsListViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell
        cell.setPost(posts[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
}
```

As you can see it's quite standard. I'm not handling the tap on the status bar, just using default behaviour.

[image: UIViewController]

Comment: please add some code to explain better. What exactly are you doing when you are tapping on the status bar?

Comment: It's quite difficult to add just some code... however I'm not handling the tap, just using default behaviour.

Comment: Could be a dirty try. but, set scrollsToTop = true. 
Yes, your tableView already scrolls but not to the top. So this could help.

Comment: Nope, still the same. I noticed that without overriding the height of a cell to UITableView.automaticDimension, it works. Of course I still need automatic height so it's not a solution, but maybe this can help...

Comment: I see! based on your inputs, I see that as a potential cause of this behavior. Check and compare the default height of your prototype cell and the height of your first row after data is populated. (that means after the row height has automatically been taken). It would definitely be higher.
So I think you should call `tableView.layoutIfNeeded()` after data is populated.

Comment: like - 

`open override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

 }`

Comment: I'm trying but it doesn't work. I also tried to set estimatedHeightForRowAt using the actual height: it fails even worse, scrolling just some pixels. There must be something wrong with it.